# How to use Image Literal in the latest Xcode version 13?

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, image

I have tried the #imageliteral method but it seems to not working also. I need to use many images in an array so is there any alternative to it or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

*#imageLiteral(*

without the closing parenthesis, In this way you can add images in Xcode 13.

Comment: is cool, can you share more magic code like this? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use #imageLiteral like you did befor but then add the parentheses and you will get a blank image. Then click the image and you probably know what to do after that

Answer (score 0):

Dear @Amish to solve this problem you can use the following instruction:

Syntax:

```
who.what=value

Image1.image=UIImage(named:"Image2")
```

write your image name in parentheses